# Run audio capture for specified time for Android on ADB

Tags: android, command-line, timeout, adb, audio-recording

I'm trying to capture audio from a microphone I have hooked up to an Android board. For this, I'm using tinycap via ADB. I want to create audio files that are 10 seconds long.

When I run the command:

```
tinycap sdcard/testadudio.wav
```

and CTRL + C manually, it generates an audio file and captures the audio. With command:

```
timeout 10s tinycap sdcard/testadudio.wav
```

It generates a broken audio file, with no audio.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this work on non rooted phones?

Comment: How did you find the tinymix configurations for recording? I'm looking for tinymix configuration for recording a voice call but I don't know where I can find tinymix configs

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+C sends `SIGNIT`, but timeout sends `SIGTERM`. Try adding `-s INT` to your timeout command.

Answer (score 1):

**This cannot be done** since privacy concerns have caused Android to shut down any attempts to record the audio stream without enabling the Tee Sink in the build. https://source.android.com/devices/audio/debugging

Disregarding this, the following part of the answer concerns tinycap:

While the actual arguments may vary, `tinycap` actually seems to support this.

Running

```
$ adb -d shell tinycap
Usage: tinycap file.wav [-D card] [-d device] [-c channels] [-r rate] 
[-b bits] [-p period_size] [-n n_periods] [-T capture time]
```

indicates that `-T` will let you control the length of the recording. However, running this on the latest version of `tinycap`, installed on my desktop linux, gives a different result:

```
$ tinycap
Usage: tinycap {file.wav | --} [-D card] [-d device] [-c channels] [-r rate]
[-b bits] [-p period_size] [-n n_periods] [-t time_in_seconds]

Use -- for filename to send raw PCM to stdout
```

Here, it seems, `-t` controls the length of the recording.